# Active tab on page load with url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have three links

```
<a href="index.php?page=tabs">Level</a>
<a href="index.php?page=tabs">Function</a>
<a href="index.php?page=tabs">Programs</a>
```

I want to call this tab active on page load

php url is like this

`index.php?page=tabs` (for open the page with these all tabs)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs faq-cat-tabs">
   <li><a href="#faq-cat-1" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Levels</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#faq-cat-3" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Functions</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#faq-cat-2" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Programme Calander</a></li>
</ul>
```

On each click I want to active different tabs active in previous list

My php page for url is like this

```
<?php include 'Header.php';

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = trim($_GET['page']);
    include $page.'.php';

}else{
    include 'Home.php';
}

?>
<?php include 'Footer.php'; ?>
```

In short want to open tabs on page load
And I have tried `index.php?page=level#faq-cat-1` and so on but it won't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Right now, either some code is missing, or the question could be clearer.  Also, include a [mcve] to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have in your URL "www.stackoverflow.com/page#tab1" and you want to make tab1 active.

```
"www.xyz.com/page#tab1";
```

Now on load of the page get the URL

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Get the tab to make active from url link.

```
var activeTab = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

Remove old active tab class

```
$(".tab-pane").removeClass("active in");
```

Add active class to new tab

```
$("#" + activeTab).addClass("active in");
```

Or directly open tab after getting activeTab.

```
$('a[href="#'+ activeTab +'"]').tab('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at page load to display the tab in based on hash

```
$(function(){
   $('.faq-cat-tabs a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');
});
```

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap or MDB
then you have just check the hash url and hit the tab event of that Anchor URL

```
const anchor = window.location.hash;
$(`a[href="${anchor}"]`).tab('show');
```